# Display a 'View fence' button if exists but display 'No fence' button if it does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object of markers, the key is the contacts name.
And an array of objects which has a 'contact' item which is also the contacts name.

I am trying to detect if the contact has an existing "geofence" from the array of objects and show a 'view fence' button, and display a 'No Fence' button if it does not.

The fences are stored in an array of objects called `fencesCookie`

Code so far:

```
function fenceButton(id) {
    for (var key in markers) {
        if (markers[key].id === id) {
            $.each(fencesCookie, function (i, f) {
                if (key === f.contact) {
                    menu.add(strings[strLang].viewfence, 'fence',
                    function(){
                        viewFence(f.lat, f.lng, f.radius);
                        menu.close();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No Fence : "+key+" "+f.contact)
                }
            });
            if ($.isEmptyObject(fencesCookie)) {
                menu.add('No Fence', 'nofence',
                function(){
                    menu.close();
                });             
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The console.log is spitting out all the unmatched items, so adding the 'No Fence' button code here results in multiple buttons, rather than just a View or No Fence button.

Am i going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vince, without seeing what's in 'fencesCookie' or what's in your 'markers' object it is hard to say but it's either:

1. [Less likely] You have multiple matching id's in your 'markers' object and it's causing the '(markers[key].id === id)' to give a positive result each time and jumping into the cookie loop again.
2. [Most Likely] Your test for a matching key in 'fencesCookie' is failing for all cases except when it matches so you're printing out a 'No Fence' button for each key in 'fenceCookie'or for all but one key.

I changed the order and added a variable to check for a match after the loop has finished.
Try this out (or something like it):

```
function fenceButton(id) {
    for (var key in markers) {
        if (markers[key].id === id) {
            // set a variable to test if we find a match
            // we'll set it to true if we find one
            var match = false;
            // Test that fencesCookie exists
            if ($.isEmptyObject(fencesCookie)) {
                // if not 
                menu.add('No Fence', 'nofence',
                function(){
                    menu.close();
                });             
            } else {
                // if it does
                $.each(fencesCookie, function (i, f) {
                    // loop through the cookie and match on the f.contact
                    if (key === f.contact) {
                        // set match to true
                        match = true;
                        // create the 'view' button
                        menu.add(strings[strLang].viewfence, 'fence',
                        function(){
                            viewFence(f.lat, f.lng, f.radius);
                            menu.close();
                        });
                    } 
                });
                // The loop is done so test 'match' to see if we found a match
                if (match === false) {
                    // No matches so create the 'No Fence' button
                    console.log("No Fence : "+key+" "+f.contact)
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```